# How to Start New activity in Tab without using ActvityGroup

Tags: android, tabs, android-activity, android-tabhost

I have not used the activityGroup in my project. Now I'm not is a position to implement the whole project using Activity group.

- is it nesssory that I must implement the activityGroup class in my project to do so?

If yes then please give links for the basic tutorial of activityGroup implementation.

Here is my MainActvity.java which loads 4 other actvities in 4 tabs.

```
    public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {
        TabHost tabHost;
        Context context = MainActivity.this;
        Button btnGo;
        TabSpec spec;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
            btnGo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_GO);     
            tabHost = getTabHost();
            // Android tab
            Intent intentHome = new Intent();
            intentHome.setClass(this, Home.class);
            TabSpec tabSpecHome = tabHost
                    .newTabSpec("Home")
                    .setIndicator("Home",
                            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home))
                    .setContent(intentHome);

            tabHost.addTab(tabSpecHome);

            Intent intentNowReading = new Intent().setClass(this, NowReading.class);
            TabSpec tabSpecNowReading = tabHost
                    .newTabSpec("Now Reading")

                    .setIndicator("Now Reading",
                            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.now_reading))
                    .setContent(intentNowReading);
            tabHost.addTab(tabSpecNowReading);

            Intent intentFavourite = new Intent().setClass(this, Favorites.class);
            TabSpec tabSpecFavourite = tabHost
                    .newTabSpec("Favourite")
                    .setIndicator("Favorites",
                            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.favorites))
                    .setContent(intentFavourite);
            tabHost.addTab(tabSpecFavourite);

            Intent intentProfile = new Intent().setClass(this, Profile.class);
            TabSpec tabSpecProfile = tabHost
                    .newTabSpec("Profile")
                    .setIndicator("Profile",
                            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.profile))
                    .setContent(intentProfile);
            tabHost.addTab(tabSpecProfile);
            tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag("Home");
...}
```

[image]

- now I want to start the new activity in the Home tab area on the click event of Go button.(See the picture).
- please note that I do not want to impelement the ActivityGroup class, How can I do that without this.
- New Actvity must load in the HomeTab's area, not on the full screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActvityGroup is a bad idea, this is old, deprecated API, don't use it.

You have to use [Fragments API](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), just create a Fragment and add it to layout using FragmentTransaction, thats all what you need.